# get elements not present when comparing two branches

Tags: git, git-diff

I am actually comparing two org using git where each org is represented by a distinct branch.
I tried to execute the following git command to list all differences into a file :

```
git diff origin/prod origin/dev --name-only >> diff.txt
```

I noticed therefore that elements that are not present in dev but prod are not showing in my diff.txt file. Only the file that exist on both org but are different somehow are listed.

How to get also those present in prod but not in dev?

Comment: Are you sure the file exists in one commit and not in the other? `git diff --name-only` lists such files for me.

Comment: I am not using git diff for commits but on branches. I am doing a git diff branch1 branch2

Comment: `git diff br1 br2` means `git diff $(git rev-parse br1) $(git rev-parse br2)`. Try it and see. Diff can't compare more than two commits at a time (well, with the exception of *combined diffs*, but that's another kettle of horses of another color).

Comment: Or to rephase what torek said, a branch is just a name for a commit.